# Playing flash file on my DVD player

Tags: flash, dvd

I want to make my flash file to play on my dvd player. It has some scripted buttons on it, so it is important that this works, is it even possible to make a swf into a DVD format and then play it with scripted buttons?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't any way to directly convert a flash movie with interactivity into a DVD menu.

The best you can do is to import the assets for the flash movie into some DVD authoring software and use that to build the interactivity that you need.

You will find that the DVD menu format has many limitations over what is possible with flash.